# Combining WHEN and LIST with CONTAINS in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

If I do want to go a party when my girlfriend or my best friend is there, no matter what. If they are not there, I would not go if there was a murderer. But if no murderer is at the party, I would go still if funny Pete is there.

The following is not valid Kotlin code as I cannot use .contains in this way. What would be a similar clean way of writing this?

```
val peopleAtParty = listOf("girlfriend","bestFriend","murderer","funnyPete")

val goingToParty = when(peopleAtParty.contains) {
    "girlfriend","bestFriend" -> true
    "murderer" -> false
    "funnyPete" -> true
    else -> false
}
```

Comment: You'll probably just have to do `val goingToParty = "girlfriend" in peopleAtParty || "bestFriend" in peopleAtParty || ("funnyPete" in peopleAtParty && "murderer" !in peopleAtParty)`

Comment: @user: thanks for contributing, I have chosen the other answer because it's clean and easy to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
    val goingToParty = when {
        peopleAtParty.contains("girlfriend") -> true
        peopleAtParty.contains("bestFriend") -> true
        peopleAtParty.contains("murderer") -> false
        peopleAtParty.contains("funnyPete") -> true
        else -> false
    }
```

Comment: You could probably use `in` to make it a bit shorter, or maybe a local function like `fun atParty(s: String) = s in peopleAtParty`

Comment: sure, but he want try with "when", we have 1000 another a bit shorter ways

Comment: @user and ur code dont working ;)  murderer returning false and your code checking list

Comment: @Majster: I find your solution is actually better readable than the invalid code in my question. thanks!!